# Having some a map and some root we'd like to follow what standard algorithm would help in creating path?

Tags: c++, search, graph, path, root

We have some set of points (each point has its X and Y) and a multy map of roots [point, point]. We can move via roots from any point to any in any possible direction. We are given some path of 2d points we want to follow as close to as possible:

[image: map]

how to calculate a path like this:

[image]

that would look as alike as possible to given path? What are usefull algorithms that can do such thing (and are thay implemented in Boost [Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) or [Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) or any other common opensource C++ library)?

Comment: Define "as close to as possible".  i.e. what metric do you want to minimise?

Comment: euclidean distance from possible roots or points

Comment: I see two ways to interpret your problem. 1) For each point in the path, find the closest point in the graph, return a path through the graph that connect these points. 2) Traverse the lines connecting the input points and continuously track the closest point in the graph, returning a path of the closest points that were passed during the traversal. Which of these (if either) did you intend?

Comment: Have a look at the boost::graph library and tutorial: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really cute little problem. If your graph is well connected a greedy approach might work quite well. As in: (1) set current position to be the node closest to the start of the path, (2) move to the adjacent node which is closest to the next point in the path until there is no closer point, (3) select next point in path and goto (2) if not finished.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

double sq(double const d)
{
    return d * d;
}

size_t min_dist_point(
    std::vector<double> const& x,
    std::vector<double> const& y,
    std::vector<bool> const& adjacent,
    double const fx,
    double const fy
)
{
    size_t const points = x.size();

    double min_dist_sq = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    size_t min_point;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < points; ++j) {
        if (!adjacent[j]) { continue; }
        double const dist_sq = sq(x[j] - fx) + sq(y[j] - fy);

        if (dist_sq < min_dist_sq) {
            min_point = j;
            min_dist_sq = dist_sq;
        }
    }
    assert(min_dist_sq != std::numeric_limits<double>::max());

    return min_point;
}

template <class out_t>
out_t f(
    std::vector<double> const& x,
    std::vector<double> const& y,
    std::vector<std::vector<bool> > adjacent,
    std::vector<double> const& follow_x,
    std::vector<double> const& follow_y,
    out_t out
)
{
    size_t const points = x.size();
    size_t const follow_len = follow_x.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < points; ++i) {
        adjacent[i][i] = 1;
    }

    std::vector<bool> const all (points, true);
    size_t pos = min_dist_point(x, y, all, follow_x[0], follow_y[0]);
    *out++ = pos;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < follow_len; ++i) {
        for (;;) {
            size_t const next = min_dist_point(x, y, adjacent[pos], follow_x[i], follow_y[i]);
            if (next == pos) { break; }
            *out++ = (pos = next);
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

If this algorithm gets stuck in cycles you will need A* search.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html